# How do I prove $A \cup\varnothing = A$ and $A \cap\varnothing = \varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A \cup \emptyset = A \qquad \text{and} \qquad A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$$

I know these are identities but I'm not sure how to get started.

Comment: Just use the definition of sets.

Comment: Chris, you might want to accept the answer you've found most useful. This motivates people to answer you questions.

Answer (score 7):

For the first one.

Let $a\in A\cup \varnothing$. Then $a\in A$ or $a\in\varnothing$. Since $a\in\varnothing$ is false regardless of $a$, but we assumed $a\in A\cup \varnothing$, it must be that $a\in A$ is true, so that $A\cup \varnothing \subseteq A$. Conversely, $A\cup \varnothing \supseteq A$ trivially, so $A=A\cup\varnothing$.

Can you do the other?

Comment: *Much* nicer. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

These tautologies are useful. 
$$P\wedge T \iff P$$
and 
$$P\vee F \iff P.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $X$ and $Y$ are sets and you would like to prove $X = Y$ then you do so in two steps

1. Prove $X \subseteq Y$, that is, prove that every element contained in $X$ is also contained in $Y$.
2. Prove $Y \subseteq X$, that is, prove that every element contained in $Y$ is also contained in $X$.

Alternatively, if you would like to prove $X = \emptyset$ you must prove that $X$ contains no elements.  Use the first strategy for $A \cup \emptyset = A$ and use the second for $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.