# How does logic and elementary set theory work together to prove $A \cup \varnothing = A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, soft-question, proof-writing

In [How do I prove $A \cup\varnothing = A$ and $A \cap\varnothing = \varnothing$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314450/how-do-i-prove-a-cup-varnothing-a-and-a-cap-varnothing-varnothing?rq=1)

A proof was given reproduced here:

Prove: $A \cup \varnothing = A$

> Let $a\in A\cup \varnothing$. Then $a\in A$ or $a\in\varnothing$.
>   Since $a\in\varnothing$ is false regardless of $a$, but we assumed
>    $a\in A\cup \varnothing$, it must be that $a\in A$ is true, so that
>    $A\cup \varnothing \subseteq A$. Conversely, $A\cup \varnothing
>  \supseteq A$ trivially, so $A=A\cup\varnothing$.

I never took a course on elementary logic (or real analysis for that matters) so it escapes me:

> it must be that $a\in A$ is true $\implies A\cup \varnothing \subseteq A$

How does a truth statement (a sentence in Englisch) just translates into a set inclusion??

Should there be something in between:

> it must be that $a\in A$ is true [and in logic, "true" relates to set inclusion like this] $ A\cup \varnothing \subseteq A$

Can someone bridge this gap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how the full logic of the proof goes:

1. $a \in A \cup \emptyset$
2. $a \in A \cup \emptyset \rightarrow (a \in A ~\vee~ a \in \emptyset)$ by the definition of the union of two sets.
3. $(a \in A ~\vee~ a \in \emptyset)$ by *[Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens)*.
4. $a \notin \emptyset$ by the definition of the empty set as the set with no elements.
5. $(a \in A ~\vee~ a \in \emptyset) ~\wedge~ (a \notin \emptyset) \rightarrow a \in A $ by [disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism).
6. $a \in A$ by *Modus ponens*
7. $a \in A \cup \emptyset \rightarrow a \in A$ by the transitive property of the conditional operator.
8. $\therefore ~ A \cup \emptyset \subseteq A$ by the definition of a subset.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. What gives us "$a \in A \cup \emptyset \rightarrow (a \in A ~\vee~ a \in \emptyset)$"? I know it is obvious but would be the proof for this? The left hand side has no logic operator, how does the logic operator $\lor$ just appear on the right hand side?

Comment: We define $A \cup B$ to be equal to the set $\{x|x \in A \vee x \in B\}$, so if some element $a$ is in the union of two sets, then it must be in one of those two sets.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the union had a definition. In engineering we just use proof by intuition. It works until someone asks you to give a formal proof, then you crash

Comment: Also can you add a simple intuition to this "disjunctive syllogism" thing? I looked up on Wikipedia and it seems pretty wild

Comment: Disjunctive syllogism says that if P or Q is true, and Q is false, then P must be true. P or Q is true if and only if P is true, Q is true, or P and Q are both true. If Q is false, then the only way P or Q can be true is if P is true.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of $B\subseteq A$ is $\forall x\in B:x\in A$
Substitute $B=A\cup\emptyset$ and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "Let $a \in A \cup \emptyset$" says that $a$ can be any element of $A \cup \emptyset$. So by showing that $a \in A$, we have shown that any element of $A \cup \emptyset$ is an element of $A$, or equivalently that $A \cup \emptyset \subset A$ (this is in fact the definition of subset).